# Issue accessing plotly dash behind nginx

Tags: nginx, plotly-dash

I have a dash plotly running on a VM with ip address 192.168.8.3 on port 5050. Locally, I can access the dashboard using the url http://192.168.8.3:5050.

Now I am trying to enable access via Nginx on http://myserver.com/dashboard/devs. However, when i try access it, in the browser console there is some files not found:

```
GET http://myserver.com/assets/header.css?m=1597279663.0
GET http://myserver.com/assets/typography.css?m=1597279663.0
```

This is my nginx configuration:

```
server {
    server_name myserver.com;
    
    location /dashboard/devs {
        rewrite ^/(dashboard/devs)/(.*) /$2 break;
        proxy_pass http://192.168.8.3:5050;
        proxy_set_header X-Real_IP $remote_addr
        ...
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it was resolved using flask to redirect "/" requests to "/dashboard/devs/". The nginx configuration was left untouched.